# Python3, column names from array - numpy or pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset in the below format.

```
id  A   B   C   D   E
100 1   0   0   0   0
101 0   1   1   0   0
102 1   0   0   0   0
103 0   0   0   1   1
```

I would like to convert this into below:

```
100, A
101, B C
102, A
103, D E
```

How do I do this ? I tried numpy argsort but I am new to Python and finding this challenging.
Appreciate any help in this.

`python
df3 = df1.set_index("cust_id").apply(lambda col: ','.join(col[lambda x: x == 1].index), axis = 1)`

`python
df3`

```
cust_id
1375586                      ind_cco_fin_ult1
1050611                      ind_cco_fin_ult1
1050612    ind_deco_fin_ult1,ind_viv_fin_ult1
dtype: object
```

`python
df2`

```
cust_id
1375586                       ind_cco_fin_ult1
1050611                       ind_cco_fin_ult1
1050612    ind_ctma_fin_ult1,ind_deco_fin_ult1
dtype: object
```

`python
metrics.mapk(df2,df3,7)`

```
0.82879818594104293
```

```python
list1=[['ind_cco_fin_ult1'], ['ind_cco_fin_ult1'], ['ind_deco_fin_ult1', 'ind_viv_fin_ult1'] ]
list2=[['ind_cco_fin_ult1'], ['ind_cco_fin_ult1'], ['ind_ctma_fin_ult1', 'ind_deco_fin_ult1'] ]

```

`python
metrics.mapk(list2,list1,7)`

```
0.83333333333333337
```

Thank you a lot for the help, I was able to try few steps.
I am trying to test mapk but the apply method does not seem to give what I really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
df.set_index("id").apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row[row == 1].index), axis = 1)

#id
#100      A
#101    B C
#102      A
#103    D E
#dtype: object
```